# Why does $eq behave differently to $ne in casbah?

Tags: scala, casbah

Why does $eq behave differently to $ne in casbah?

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._

object O{  
   val x = "user" $ne "bwmcadams"  // Compile fine
   val y = "user" $eq "bwmcadams"  // fails to compile: value = is not a member of string
}
```

Built with:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>casbah-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$eq` operator was added in a later version of Casbah.  Try changing your Casbah version to 2.6.3.

Comment: Hey, you're right. I was looking in the old API docs. However, it doesn't do anything interesting (just wraps a regular DBObject): https://github.com/mongodb/casbah/blob/master/casbah-query/src/main/scala/CoreOperators.scala#L122

Comment: Looks like that was it. Side note: looks like casbah is up to 3.0.0, but only available for scala 2.9.0, sadly...

Comment: Casbah 3.0.0 was never officially released and became Casbah 2.3 iirc

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$eq`, try `->` (as a regular tuple). There is no `$eq` operator in MongoDB: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ -- equality is the default operator.

Update: It looks like they've removed those conversions from tuples to DBObjects. Try a regular Map:

```
val y: DBObject = Map("user" -> "bwmcadams")
```

Update 2: See cmbaxter's answer--they actually did add `$eq` as an operator ~July 2013, but you don't really need to use it.